# How can I tell how many pages will be printed from command line?

Tags: python, printing, lpr

I am currently using lpr to print from the command line. 
I am also using a python backend.

Is there anyway I can see how many pages are going to print/have printed for a specific file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short of passing the job through a RIP (Raster Image Processor) there's no easy way to do it. In the Linux and Unix world print jobs are passed around as PostScript files. PostScript actually is a fully fledged Turing complete programming language. Which means that the [Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) applies to them.

So the only option is to pass it through a PostScript RIP (raster image processor) and see how many pages come out of it; don't forget to add some timeout.

Ghostscript is such a RIP and it offers a nullpage output device, which is mostly good for counting pages. Use the following command line

```
timeout 120s gs -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dSAFER -sDEVICE=nullpage <file> \
| egrep '^Page' \
| wc -l
```

The first command uses the `timeout` command to invoke *Ghostscript* in a way that it doesn't wait for user input, processes a whole file in one, disables known unsafe features and produces no raster output. This pipes into *grep* looking for lines in the diagnostic output of `gs` starting with `Page`; one such line is produced for each page. Finally this is piped through `wc` to count the total number of lines that match. If `gs` doesn't finish after 120 seconds it is aborted.

Be aware that this is still susceptible to malicious PostScript files (even with `-dSAFER`).